# Is there any product–division mathematical symbol?

Tags: calculus, notation

In mathematics everybody knows the plus–minus sign, ±, used to indicate a symbol that may be replaced by either the plus and minus signs, + or −, allowing the formula to represent two values or two equations.
There also exist a minus-plus sign ∓.

But I haven't been able to find a product–division sign denoting that both multiplication and division can be both possible.

Is there anything like that?
Who decides what symbols can be invented and used and what other not?

It could be any combination of these symbols:
[image]

And it could be used as
[image]

Comment: I don't believe there's a symbol for this, I think people would just write e.g. "$x\cdot y^{\pm 1}.$"

Comment: Over a field, (such as the real numbers) the division operation isn't (or doesn't need to be) defined.  Instead of dividing we multiply by the inverse.  As for the rules of notation, mathematicians are free to invent the notation that suits their work.  Their peers can then choose to propagate that notation if it is useful to do so.  But, the first person to investigate a topic generally gets to choose the notation.